# Block a column with text format so that they do not enter values in numerical format in Excel

Tags: excel, format

I have an excel file where I have two columns, one is called "NUMERIC" and the other "TEXT". I would like to apply a constraint or validation that prohibits me from inserting values in text format in the "NUMERICAL" column and vice versa. The objective of all this is to avoid entering codes with leading zeros in the "TEXT" field and losing these 0s.

I have tried to click on the pop-up window of the Home part -> Alignment and within the cell format, in the protect tab, I have marked the locked option, even so I can still put text in the "NUMERICA" column and vice versa, As shown in the picture.

[image]

In this image we can see that the value that I am selecting is in text format and that I have the cell supposedly protected

[image]

In this second image you can see that I have the column in numerical format, however it lets me put values in text format and it doesn't remove the 0s to the left.

What I definitely need is that in the "NUMBERS" column it only allows me to copy values in numerical format, and in the TEXT column it only allows me to copy values in text format, if I copy a numerical value it will transform it into text.

Thank you for everything, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are several misstakes you did.
Start on a NEW sheet.
Mark row A
Format as Text

[image]

Then everything you enter will be text.
Leading zeros will remain.

In row B, leading zeros will cut off. This will be "numbers"

[image]

If you want change the text from column A to numbers, you can use this formula:
[image]

If you want only enter "numbers" with leading zeros in column A
you can apply this data validation:

```
=COUNTIF(A2;"<>0*")
```

change ; to , if your Excel needs

[image]

The protection thing you wrote about is for something else. No need to try that.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the countif formula works, it won't let me enter any value, whether it has 0 in front of it or not. It should be noted that not all codes have a 0 in front. What I want to achieve is that it does not transform the values into numbers

Comment: In addition to this, we usually copy the codes and paste them in the column that I want to be restricted, what I am seeing is that when I copy a value and paste it in the cell with validation, the formula behind the cell with validation and this validation is lost

Comment: I want to restrict pasting values in the cells of this column that are not in text format

Comment: @AbelPérez the countif formula works for me. However you can't use it anyway. Pasting numbers might depend on from where you copy the data also. You can try different past options (pasting values, pasting as text and so on) and see if it gives the desired result. Not to forget to format the column as text. Much more you can't do. Even data validation will be written over by pasting. User needs to know what he/she is doing.